# How to modify the themes of shinythemes?

Tags: shiny, shinythemes

How to modify the themes of `shinythemes`? For example, let us assume I want to change `darkly`'s background black.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  "How to change this black?")

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I guess one solution would be to copy the CSS of `darkly` with the modified black to the www-folder of my app and then use `theme = "darkly_modified_black.css"`. Is there a simpler solution I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include your own css-arguments, if you just want to change the background-color.
But yes, you can also copy the css of darkly, modify it, include it in the www folder and load it from there.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

css <- HTML(" body {
    background-color: #000000;
}")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(css)),
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  "How to change this black?")

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want a separate .css-file you can use `includeCSS` with the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a quite old question, but I have just found another way to do it. The `fresh` package can be helpful too. In fact, someone posted about how to change the tone of shinythemes using `NavbarPage` and I have just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789111/13997761).

This is my solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(fresh)

ui <- fluidPage(

  use_theme(create_theme(
    theme = "default",
    bs_vars_global(
      body_bg = "#000",
      text_color = "#FFF"
    ))),
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  
  "How to change this black?")

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can create themes to use with:

- Shiny itself, with shiny::fluidPage or shiny::navbarPage or themes from Bootswatch (https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/vars-shiny.html)
- Shinydashboard (https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/vars-shinydashboard.html)
- bs4Dash (https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/vars-bs4dash.html)

Here you have more [info](https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/fresh.html) about the package.