# Change the title header color permanently in shiny dashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny dashboard below and I need to change the color of the header that includes the title permanently. Now when I hover over it returns to previous color.

```
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width=400
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

        /* logo */
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                              background-color: #E7FF6E;
                              }'))) 
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom theme to use with {shinydashboard} with the {fresh} package, more documentation here : https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/vars-shinydashboard.html

Here an example to modify header background color:

```
library(fresh)
# Create the theme
mytheme <- create_theme(
  adminlte_color(
    light_blue = "#E7FF6E"
  )
)


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Settings", tabName = "settings", icon = icon("sliders"))
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(

    use_theme(mytheme) # <-- use the theme
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: have you got any idea why I cannot change the width of the sidebar after using your solution? It always remains the same.

Comment: oh I found how.